# Where do I define UtliSnips snippets for Python?

Tags: neovim, plugin-ultisnips, snippets

I am using UltiSnips for my snippets. I have only used LaTeX snippets with UltiSnips, which I defined in a `tex.snippets` file inside of an `UltiSnips` directory in my `runtimepath`.

Now, I would like to write snippets for Python as well. How do I do it? Is there a particular name I have to give to the `.snippets` file? Is there a different syntax for Python snippets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:UltiSnipsEdit` will automatically open ultisnips for current filetype. From there you can see that it's supposed to be `python.snippets`.

Answer (score 3):

UltiSnips uses a strategy similar to how Vim detects `:h ftplugins`. That is, it will look for the filenames that match the following pattern in your UltiSnips directory: `ft.snippets`, `ft_*.snippets`, or `ft/*`, where `ft` is replaced with your Vim filetype (`python`, `c`, etc.) and `*` matches any string including the empty string. A table from `:h UltiSnips-how-snippets-are-loaded`:

> ```
> snippet filename         filetype ~
> ruby.snippets            ruby
> perl.snippets            perl
> c.snippets               c
> c_my.snippets            c
> c/a                      c
> c/b.snippets             c
> all.snippets             all
> all/a.snippets           all
> ```

So, to write snippets for the `python` filetype, you can use `UltiSnips/python.snippets` (or `UltiSnips/python_classes.snippets`, or `UltiSnips/python/classes.snippets`, for example).

All `*.snippet` files use the same syntax, regardless of filetype.